Anbox Cloud appliance: Error: not authorized
I installed Anbox cloud appliance through the guide for a dedicated machine, an Ubuntu 22.04 server, which is being virtualized by virtual machine manager application on Linux. However, when I want to use amc commands, it shows the following error message:
Error: not authorized

I want to know if anybody else has faced the same issue or probably knows what is going on?
